# Jquery Flipcard Animation to flip on toggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery flipcard animation - http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/36/

Now the way this flip card works is it shows the top div, and hide all divs below it. IF you click on a link in the first div, it flips to the second div andsoforth.When it gets to the last div, it flips back the the first one again on clicking an anchor tag. Now I want 3 anchor tags on the front flip card(first div) and each link(a tag) should have its own back flip card/backsideDiv. currently, in my example, when you click on the first link, it loops through the other 2 links' backsideDivs/flipcards as well. I want it to go back to the main front div again(not flipping to the other links' backflip divs).
So each set of anchor tag/back div pair should operate independently. Hoped I explained it well enough.

I would really appreciate any help

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much of easy use of functions for quickFlip... This isn't pretty, but I think I got what you're looking for or at-least close. http://jsfiddle.net/2WbYG/10/

Comment: man, you are awesome, I tried so many things but I couldn't get it as far as you just did. Thanks a lot, will implement it on my website tomorrow and let you know(the complete picture looks way better, this is just for functionality)

Comment: I would just like to know, did you need to look at the included jquery file to be able to make the changes you did? or was it possible without knowing the seeing the jquery.quickflip.source.js file?

Comment: I had to look at the quickflip js file, tried looking up the api on their site first, but there wasn't much info. And as I looked in the source code, it was clear why... I noticed there was a flip function, but was not easy to get to. That's why I called the constructor manually instead of using .quickFlip() since I was then able to call flip(). Btw, it seems that the first param in flip() is the index of all the flip cards, so if you have a 2nd flip card on the page it would have to be flip(1) as it is the 2nd.

Comment: Yes I actually do have other flipcards that does not need the functionality as the one described in this question. The 'problem' I have here, works fine for them. So you say I should just add another line of code: qf.flip(1)(0, $(this).index() + 1); to the existing one? Thanks a lot again, appreciated.

Comment: To make it more dynamic, you could find the index of the flipper and use that. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zbY7n/